# rails 4 Multiple user models (STI) polymorphic - nested attribute to extra profile table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested, nested-attributes, sti

I have challenge to find way how to submit value in 'company_profiles' table for 'Company' and 'company' is polymorphic to User. Already tried so many ways and no luck. Always getting - 'Unpermitted parameter: company_profiles'. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
..app/controllers/application_controller

 protect_from_forgery with: :exception <br>
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:company_id, :company_profiles_attributes => [ :first_name_legal]) }
```

```
 .app/controllers/companies/registrations_controller.rb
# GET /resource/sign_up
def new
build_resource({})
resource.company_profile
set_minimum_password_length
yield resource if block_given?
respond_with self.resource
end

# POST /resource
def create
build_resource(sign_up_params)
resource.save
yield resource if block_given?
if resource.persisted?
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  set_minimum_password_length
  respond_with resource
end
end

def sign_up_params
allow = [:company_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
         :company_profiles_attributes => [:first_name_legal]]
params.require(resource_name).permit(allow)
end
```

```
Models:
..app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
belongs_to :role, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :company_profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_profile
validates_uniqueness_of :email
end

..app/models/company.rb
class Company < User
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
has_one :user, :as => :role
belongs_to :company_profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

..app/models/company_profile.rb
class CompanyProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users
has_many :companies
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies
end
```

```
Registration form: 
 ..app/views/companies/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |fc| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
  <%= fc.label :email %><br/>
  <%= fc.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= fc.label :password %>
  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
  <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
  <% end %><br />
  <%= fc.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

 <div class="field">
 <%= fc.label :password_confirmation %><br />
 <%= fc.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
 </div>

  <%= fc.fields_for :company_profiles do |fa| %>
      <%= fa.text_field :first_name_legal, :class => "form-control", :id => "exampleInputName1",  :placeholder => "*First name", :required => true, :maxlength => 35 %>
  <% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= fc.submit "Sign up" %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

> Server logs
>
> Started POST "/companies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-30 12:17:19 -0700
>   Processing by Companies::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nG3FmJOunzJfekYo0LE8OOK6rR9lp8kjW6pbXJl6N2QggiZsmrS/N+KU/r6IfwSVUep0Elmiir+d/w+vULTrQw==", "company"=>{"email"=>"some@superman.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "company_profiles"=>{"first_name_legal"=>"super man company"}}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
>
> Unpermitted parameter: company_profiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer if anyone will have this issue try following:

> 1- Change everything to singular.
>
> 2- Change -
>       GET /resource/sign_up 
>       def new 
>       build_resource({}) 
>       resource.company_profile = CompanyProfile.new 
>   ....
>
> 3-  Update - class CompanyProfile < ActiveRecord::Base 
>   belongs_to :company 
>    accepts_nested_attributes_for :company 
>   end
>
> 4-  Update -  class Company < User 
>    has_many :company_profiles
>   
>    accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_profiles 
>  end
>
> 5- And add - company_profile_id to user table

And all works

Answer (score 0):

You have a `belongs_to` association on `company_profile` for `company`. Change `company_profiles` to `comapny_profile` in the entire code.

Comment: Changed everywhere to company_profile and now field not presented on registration screen at all, any idea?